# "if variable not in list" not working returning true all the time

Tags: python, if-statement, return

Why is this line of code always returning true?

```
def GetPlayersMove(self):
    self.move = input("Enter Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
    if self.move.lower() not in ["rock" "paper", "scissors"]:
        print("Error")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code is missing `,`.

```
["rock" "paper", "scissors"]
#      ^
```

`"rock" "paper"` is equivalent to `"rockpaper"`:

```
>>> ["rock" "paper", "scissors"]
['rockpaper', 'scissors']
>>>
```

See [String literal concatenation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)